# Nested operations with Razor View Engine

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-3

I cannot figure out how to do "nested" operation in Razor. For example how to use IF inside FOREACH. VisualStudio throws compile-time error on following block, saying "Invalid expression term 'if' "

```
@foreach (var document in Model) {

    @if (document.Item.Count > 0) {
        <div>
            @MvcHtmlString.Create(document.Items[0].ContentPresenter)
        </div>
    }

}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Don't you just need to drop the `@` off the `@if` and make it:

```
@foreach (var document in Model) {
    if (document.Item.Count > 0) {
        <div>
            @MvcHtmlString.Create(document.Items[0].ContentPresenter)
        </div>
    }
}
```

Sorry I haven't worked with Razor but isn't its selling point the automatic switching back and forth between code and HTML based on context?